# Google Cloud DNS New zone

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I create new zone to Google Cloud DNS, change domain registrants NS records to pointing  ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com, dig is showing correct information from authoritative NS but records doesn't appears on public DNS, is other configuration needed? or i must wait?

```
dig mydomain.com @ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5 <<>> mydomain.com @ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12022
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
mydomain.com.                                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com                300     IN      A       x.x.x.x

;; Query time: 176 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.38.107#53(216.239.38.107)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 23 21:49:38 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the information to propagate throughout the Domain Name System. This depends on the time-to-live setting of each RRset. If you just created the zone and switched the nameservers in the registrar, you need to wait for the TTL of the **nameserver** records to expire - they are just records in the parent zone.

`dig +trace mydomain.com` should help to ensure that everything is set up properly.